# Creating a altjs flux store for fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flux

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to write a flux store and action that works in just fetching data from my express API using [altjs](http://alt.js.org/guide/async/)

```
import $ from 'jquery';

const utils = {

myProfile: () => {
    return $.ajax({
      url: '/myProfile',
      type: 'GET'
    });
  }
};
```

This is how I believe I should write my GET request for just grabbing a user's profile (which should return a json with user info).

then for my store :

```
import UserActions from 'actions/UserActions';
import alt from 'altInstance';
class UserStore {

constructor() {
   this.userProfile = [];
   this.on('init', this.bootstrap);
   this.on('bootstrap', this.bootstrap);
   this.bindListeners({
   fetchUserProfile: UserActions.FETCHUSERPROFILE,
     });
  }

fetchUserProfile(profile) {
    this.userProfile = profile;
  }
}
export default alt.createStore(UserStore, 'UserStore');
```

However the action is where i'm the most clueless

```
import alt from 'altInstance';
import UserWebAPIUtils from 'utils/UserWebAPIUtils';
fetchProfile(){
    this.dispatch();
    UserWebAPIUtils.getProfile()
      //what do we do with it to let our store know we have the data?
      });
         }
      }
  }
```

All im trying to do, is grab data from the server, tell my store we've recieved the data and fill the userprofile array with the data from our api, and the messenger for telling our store is through a dispatcher which belongs to 'actions' correct? I've looked at a lot of tutorials but I still dont feel very confident on how I am thinking about this. What if I wanted to update data through a POST request what would that be like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through altjs doc it seems like they recommend doing the async operations from actions. I prefer this approach as well because it keeps stores synchronous and easy to understand. Based on their example

LocationAction

```
LocationsFetcher.fetch()
  .then((locations) => {
    // we can access other actions within our action through `this.actions`
    this.actions.updateLocations(locations);
  })
  .catch((errorMessage) => {
    this.actions.locationsFailed(errorMessage);
  });
```

Basically they are fetching the information and then triggering 2 actions depending on the result of the request which the store is listening on to.

LocationStore

```
this.bindListeners({
  handleUpdateLocations: LocationActions.UPDATE_LOCATIONS,
  handleFetchLocations: LocationActions.FETCH_LOCATIONS,
  handleLocationsFailed: LocationActions.LOCATIONS_FAILED
});
```

When the store receives a handleUpdateLocations action which happens when the fetcher returns successfully. The store will update itself with new data and dispatch

```
handleUpdateLocations(locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
    this.errorMessage = null;
}
```

With your code you can do something similar. The fetch user profile will be triggered when data is originally requested. Here I am setting user profile to be [] which is your original init value but you can set it to anything to indicate data is being loaded. I then added 2 more methods, handleFetchUserProfileComplete and handleFetchUserProfileError which get called depending on if your fetch was successful or not. The code below is a *rough* idea of what you should have.

```
constructor() {
   this.userProfile = [];
   this.on('init', this.bootstrap);
   this.on('bootstrap', this.bootstrap);
   this.bindListeners({
       handleFetchUserProfile: UserActions.FETCH_USER_PROFILE,
       handleFetchUserProfileComplete: UserActions.FETCH_USER_PROFILE_COMPLETE,
       handleFetchUserProfileError: UserActions.FETCH_USER_PROFILE_ERROR,
   });
  }

fetchUserProfile() {
    this.userProfile = [];
}

handleFetchUserProfileComplete(profile) {
    this.userProfile = profile;
}

handleFetchUserProfileError(error) {
    this.error= error;
}

export default alt.createStore(UserStore, 'UserStore');
```

The only thing left is to trigger these 2 actions depending on the result of your fetch request in your action code

```
fetchUserProfile(){
    this.dispatch();
    UserWebAPIUtils.getProfile().then((data) => {
        //what do we do with it to let our store know we have the data?
        this.actions.fetchUserProfileComplete(data)
    })
    .catch((errorMessage) => {
        this.actions.locationsFailed(errorMessage);
    });
}

fetchUserProfileComplete(profile) {
    this.dispatch(profile);
}

fetchUserProfileError(error) {
    this.dispatch(error);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was really clear, so I just want to review it one more time 1. We are setting up our store by initializing an empty array (like we would in react), and then we have something to handle the action of fetching the user profile, however since its asynchronous we want the data structure when we start and when we end, and of course a error in case something breaks. Then in our actions we dispatch and call our API from there. Since mine was a ajax call it would be .done and .fail instead of .then and .catch, but if it was a es6 promise than that would be it right?

Comment: Right your understanding seems sound. The store registers callbacks that get called when data/error comes back or when data is initially requested. The action initially calls the API and also notifies the store that a load request has come in and then later dispatches the data or error returned by the AJAX request which callbacks have been registered for. And yeah I think if you are using jQuery for ajax then .done and .fail are the correct methods.

Comment: Actually they suggest to place this at Stores : http://alt.js.org/docs/async/ @noveyak